# Akka Complete parameter type

Tags: routes, akka

For akka routing we use complete as follows. complete(HttpResponse)

Does this complete function accept only HttpResponse from akka.scalads.HttpResponse or even org.apache.http.HttpResponse. If it does'nt accept, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**complete Parameter Types**

From [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/route-directives/complete.html#complete) you can see that `complete` accepts many different parameter types, including akka's `HttpResponse`:

```
def complete[T :ToResponseMarshaller](value: T): StandardRoute
def complete(response: HttpResponse): StandardRoute
def complete(status: StatusCode): StandardRoute
def complete[T :Marshaller](status: StatusCode, value: T): StandardRoute
def complete[T :Marshaller](status: Int, value: T): StandardRoute
def complete[T :Marshaller](status: StatusCode, headers: Seq[HttpHeader], value: T): StandardRoute
def complete[T :Marshaller](status: Int, headers: Seq[HttpHeader], value: T): StandardRoute
```

**Apache/Akka Response**

Complete does not, however, accept apache response types.

Most of the `HttpResponse` member variables are easy enough to match against a corresponding apache variable with one big exception: the `ResponseEntity` is an akka-stream `Source[ByteString, Any]`.  The apache [`HttpEntity`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) uses an `InputStream` to represent the data which is not akka/stream aware, therefore a direct translation is not possible without a pre-existing akka `ActorSystem`.

It is possible to write your own [implicit conversion function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions.html) from apache http response to akka http response which would allow you to pass apache responses to complete:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpResponse => AkkaResponse}
import org.apache.http.{HttpResponse => ApacheResponse}

implicit def apacheToAkka(apacheResponse : ApacheResponse) : AkkaResponse = ???

val apacheResponse : ApacheResponse = ???

complete(apacheResponse)
```